# How to produce unicode copyable alternative text? (with accsupp)

Tags: pdf, unicode, viewers, copy-paste, accsupp

In the following example, I can't manage to make `accsupp` store the *unicode* alternative text. The resulting PDF looks as expected but the copyable text is not the correct one. I tried this with different `accsupp` options: `method=plain`,`...=escape`, `...=pdfstringdef`, and `unicode`. (`accsupp` manual is [here](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/accsupp.pdf)). I tried with Acrobat 9.4.1 (Linux) and Evince. I am using LuaLaTeX to compile.

The idea is that when I select the equation in the next document the text `ⅆa` is copied. (In most cases only `a` gets copied.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\begin{document}

\BeginAccSupp{unicode,ActualText=ⅆa} %method=plain, ...=escape, ...=pdfstringdef
$da$
\EndAccSupp{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Big chars (characters with more than 8 bits) of LuaTeX/XeTeX are not yet fully supported. Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{accsupp}
% \usepackage{luatex85} % might be needed as a workaround https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/36

\usepackage{tikz}%\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{stringenc}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\BeginAccSuppUnicode}[1]{%
  \EdefSanitize\asu@str{#1}%
  \edef\asu@str{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\asu@ToSpaceOther
    \expandafter\asu@str\space\@nil
  }%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\asu@str\expandafter\@empty
  \expandafter\asu@ToHexUC\asu@str\relax
  \EdefUnescapeHex{\asu@str}{\asu@str}%
  \StringEncodingConvert{\asu@str}{\asu@str}{utf32be}{utf16be}%
  \EdefEscapeHex{\asu@str}{\asu@str}%
  \BeginAccSupp{%
    unicode,%
    method=hex,%
    ActualText=\asu@str
  }%
}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\9=`\ %
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\asu@SpaceOther{9}%
}
\def\asu@ToSpaceOther#1 #2\@nil{%
  #1%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \asu@SpaceOther
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\asu@ToSpaceOther#2\@nil}%
}
\def\asu@ToHexUC#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \else
    \pgfmathHex{\the\numexpr`#1+"10000000\relax}%
    \edef\asu@str{%
      \asu@str
      0\expandafter\@gobble\pgfmathresult
    }%
    \expandafter\asu@ToHexUC
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BeginAccSuppUnicode{ⅆa}
$da$
\EndAccSupp{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: mmm, I get this `! Undefined control sequence. // l.108 \pgfkeys` with `LuaLatex Version beta-0.76.0-2013122811 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (rev 4627)`.

Comment: ".. are not fully supported yet" by who? by `accsupp` or by `xe/lualatex`?

Comment: @alfC: Try with `\usepackge{tikz}`. There might be an issue with missing module dependencies of pgf/TIkZ, because the code only uses `\pgfmathHex`.

Comment: @alfC: For example, packages `stringenc` and `pdfescape`, `accsupp` could be updated to support "big chars". A clear and unambiguous specification for the support of "big chars" is probably the most difficult part.

Comment: ok, that works!, (I corrected it in your answer). Now Acrobat copied correctly `ⅆa`. Unfortunately Evince copies `da` (it really convert `ⅆ` into `d`, I don't know how), but I guess that is beyond the scope of this question. A question by the way, why did you choose the syntax `\BeginAccSupp{option} ...\EndAccSupp{}` instead of `\accsupp[options]{...}`? Is there a techical reason for that. Can one make use of the last syntax by defining a new command?

Comment: @alfC: For example, you can't use `\verb` inside an argument. The package just provides the basics, but onthe other hand, it supports different formats including plain TeX. Thus, just make a nice cozy command. e.g. something like `\newcommmand{\accsupp}[2]{\BeginAccSupp{<options>,ActualText={#1}}#2\EndAccSupp{}}` which hides the option settings from the user interface.

Comment: Can this technique be used to allow "tab" characters in `accsup`? (it is for this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194505/techniques-to-make-tabular-contents-copyable)

Comment: @alfC I have written an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195890/16967) there, which shows, how the horizontal tabulator and the line feed characters can be used with `accsupp`.

Comment: In Lualatex `1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)` this needs `\usepackage{lautex85}` to workaround a bug https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/36.

Comment: @alfC Thanks for adding the workaround with `\usepackage{luatex85}`.