# Getting correct searchable text for Devanagari text

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, indic, accessibility, accsupp

Consider this fairly minimal document, which AFAIK is the recommended way of typesetting Devanagari-script Sanskrit-language text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Chandas}

\begin{document}
किं  बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् ।
\end{document}
```

When I typeset this, even when the output is visually fine, trying to copy the text from the PDF gives incorrect results each time. I've tried with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`, with four fonts all generously available online for free: [Chandas](http://www.sanskritweb.net/cakram/), [Noto Sans Devanagari, Noto Serif Devanagari](https://www.google.com/get/noto/), [Adishila](https://adishila.com/fonts/):

- Correct text:

  - किं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् ।
- `xelatex`:

  - कं बहुना । परɕपरं जैधम् उɊपਯम् । (Chandas)
  - ɫकʌ बहुना । परȺरं द्वैधम् उत्पȡम् । (Noto Sans Devanagari)
  - ȫक बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । (Noto Serif Devanagari)
  - िकं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । (Adishila)
- `lualatex`:

  - िकं बहुना । पर�परं द्वैधम् उ�पन्नम् । (Chandas)
  - िकं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । (Noto Sans Devanagari — also, the output is broken)
  - िकं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । (Noto Serif Devanagari — also, the output is broken)
  - िकं बzना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । (Adishila)

So none of these are correct, though for some combinations, only the first syllable was problematic. (It doesn't matter that it's the first syllable; किं anywhere has the same issue.)

(Aside: This was using TeX Live 2020 so `lualatex` uses LuaHBTeX… yet the output is incorrect compared to `xelatex` for two of the fonts.)

Is there a way of getting the correct text to be copied?

I also tried wrapping every word using the `accsupp` package, like `\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=किं}किं\EndAccSupp{}` and so on, but that results in complete gibberish.

Comment: `lualatex` uses LuaHBTex, but unless you request HarfBuzz shaping your text is still shaped with the original fontshaper. Probably luaotfload's HarfBuzz support is the best bet for proper Copy&Paste, so please try LuaLaTeX and adding `Renderer=HarfBuzz` to \newfontfamily.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Wow, that worked! (For all fonts I tried.) Just before seeing your comment, I had just arrived at another solution (wrapping every word with the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171328/how-to-produce-unicode-copyable-alternative-text-with-accsupp/171335#171335)), but what you suggested is very clean and simple. Thanks! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @WillRobertson Could `fontspec` make `Renderer=HarfBuzz` the default when it’s there and the `Script=` requires it?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I never posted an update, but that solution above ended up not working in my actual use-case because of [some other unrelated(?) issue with \EveryShipout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562517/using-everyshipout-corrupts-the-copyable-text) (something to do with boxing and unboxing?), so I ended up indeed wrapping every word… might post an answer if I can dig up my files for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile with LuaLaTeX on TeX Live 2020, I get this when I copy and paste:

किं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् ।

From the following MWE, which should also save you some typing if you also want to define `\devanagarifontsf`, `\devanagarifonttt`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\ifluahbtex
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Renderer=HarfBuzz, Ligatures=TeX }
\fi

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
%% Font available at:
%% https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-deva
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\begin{document}
किं  बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् ।
\end{document}
```

This still does not, however, copy-paste correctly from XeLaTeX.

I normally use `babel`, which among other things can auto-detect the language I type in, but the solution is very similar.

As Marcel Kruger said in the comments, modern LuaLaTeX supports HarfBuzz rendering, but you need to select it.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't actually work with `xelatex` (that is, the copied output isn't right), but `\defaultfontfeatures` is good to know about.

Comment: Although this doesn't work with `xelatex` it does work with `lualatex`, so I'm accepting this as the answer: that the only way to get correct searchable/copyable text for Devanagari is to use `lualatex` with HarfBuzz. There's a particular case in which (even) this doesn't work currently ([another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562517/using-everyshipout-corrupts-the-copyable-text)), but that's more of a fringe case which may get solved in its own way, and I just discovered today that the solution I was using for that case doesn't work for regular inline text. So this is best.