# LuaHBTeX: \copy contents behave differently from \box for copy-paste -- by making contents tofu  for reordered glyphs or by adding spurious space

Tags: luatex, pdf, boxes, copy-paste, luahbtex

Here's an example of a tex `\vbox` with some devanagari text in it. My code adds contents of `\vbox` to document twice, first its copy (using `\copy`), and later itself (using `\box`). Both copies look similarly typeset in pdf, which is great. But upon copy-pasting contents from the pdf,<sup>[1]</sup> I find that the contents added by `\copy` look different from the contents added by `\box`. The former has some glyphs turned into tofu ; looks like the only glyph tofued is reordered [Devanagari](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0900) vowel sign  `ि` i.e. [U+093F](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+093F). The latter doesn't tofu anything, but adds extra spurious space after the consonant-vowel pairs where  `ि` is the consonant.

<sup>[1]</sup> I used Adobe Reader as it seems to be the only pdf reader that fully supports ActualText feature of pdf format that HarfBuzz utilizes.

Code:

```latex
% >> lualatex copyhb.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari, Renderer=HarfBuzz, Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\begin{document}

\newbox\tempbox
\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{{\devanagarifont किं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । पिताजी ज्योतिषी सुकरात\endgraf}}

Box copy: \copy\tempbox

Box contents: \box\tempbox

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of pdf]

Result of copy-paste:

> Box copy: कंबहुना । परस्परंद्वै धम्उत्पन्नम्। पताजी ज्योतषी सुकरात
>
> Box contents: कि ं बहुना । परस्परंद्वै धम्उत्पन्नम्। पि ताजी ज्योति षी सुकरात

As can be seen, the 3 tofus  placed in "Box copy" contents are for vowel notation  `ि` of consonant-vowel pairs: `कि`, `पि`, and `ति`. Also to be noticed is that this tofuing process gobbles word space, and makes `किं बहुना` as one word `कंबहुना`.  The "Box contents" has correct glyphs, but has extra spacing after same consonant-vowel pairs `कि`, `पि`, and `ति`. The original box contents luckily doesn't gobble space between words `किं` and `बहुना`. So IMO if `\box` contents get rid of extra space after consonant-vowel pairs & if contents added to pdf by `\copy` are same as those added by `\box`, then this copy-paste problem should get resolved.

Side note for `Renderer=Node`: Tofu and spurious spacing problem does not occur with Node renderer. Though it has its own known problem of reordering  `ि` and consonant of its consonant-vowel pair.

Comment: I ran into similar issues (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562453/getting-correct-searchable-text-for-devanagari-text) or rather its followup, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562517/using-everyshipout-corrupts-the-copyable-text)); I found a workaround by setting ActualText directly (as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171328/how-to-produce-unicode-copyable-alternative-text-with-accsupp/171335#171335)). I wrote a quick (hurriedly written, so possibly not very clear) [blog post](https://shreevatsa.net/post/add-ocr-layer-to-pdf/) as well.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks! Try the dev branch of luaotfload (https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/tree/dev), it resolves the discrepancy between ActualText contents of `\copy` & `\box`, and `\copy` now behaves like `\box`. Though one problem persists: the space that gets added after reordered consonant-vowel pairs that have ` ि`. I haven't tested if spurious space gets added after any other glyph combination, will file a separate issue for extra space. I will update this question after the dev branch is merged into master and released.

Comment: Thank you; I'll give it a try sometime.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Its still under works, I just found that it doesn't work with `\hbox` because his lua code does some magic using post_linebreak_filter which is not called in `\hbox`. Also, spurious space is added in cases other than that having ` ि` as vowel in consonant vowel pair. For instance space is added after `र्गु` in word `दुर्गुणों`. Here `र्`+`गु` was replaced with matra form `र्गु`.