# LuaLaTex: Multiple indexes with Devanagari page numbers in a book

Tags: luatex, babel, indexing, polyglossia

I am typesetting a Hindi book with multiple indexes and Devanagari chapter/section/page numbers. I want to use HarfBuzz rendering with LuaLaTeX, which enables error-free copy-pasting of Devanagari text from PDFs as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562453/getting-correct-searchable-text-for-devanagari-text). Unfortunately HarfBuzz rendering with XeLaTeX does not give the desired results. So I have to use LuaLaTeX. I tried an example with LuaLaTeX compiler from TexLive 2020 (on Overleaf).

This is my `latexmkrc` file.

```
add_cus_dep( 'adx', 'and', 0, 'ndx2nnd' );
sub ndx2nnd {return system( "makeindex -o \"$_[0].and\" \"$_[0].adx\"" );}
push @generated_exts, 'adx', 'and';
```

**Attempt 1: With polyglossia**

The following file compiles fine with LuaLaTeX and gives me two indexes, but with Western Arabic chapter/section/page numbers. This seems to be a known issue [here](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/406).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\newindex{top}{adx}{and}{विषयसूची}
\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{लेखकसूची}
\begin{document}
\chapter{प्रस्तावना}
\section{परिचय}
हम किंकर्तव्यविमूढ हैं।
\index[top]{विषय १}
\index[aut]{लेखक १}
\printindex[top]
\printindex[aut]
\end{document}
```

**Attempt 2: With babel**

The following file compiles fine with LuaLaTeX and gives me Devanagari chapter/section/page numbers, but no index.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[mapdigits,maparabic,main]{hindi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\newindex{top}{adx}{and}{विषयसूची}
\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{लेखकसूची}
\renewcommand\hindichaptername{अध्याय}
\begin{document}
\chapter{प्रस्तावना}
\section{परिचय}
हम किंकर्तव्यविमूढ हैं।
\index[top]{विषय १}
\index[aut]{लेखक १}
\printindex[top]
\printindex[aut]
\end{document}
```

I can use either `polyglossia` or `babel`, would prefer `polyglossia`. So appreciate any help to make either of the two examples above work. The one with `polyglossia` is missing Devanagari numbers and the one with `babel` is missing the two indexes.

Comment: The `babel` version fails because page numbers are converted at the TeX level (with `maparabic`) to the Devanagari forms, which `makeindex` doesn't understand. Isn't `mapdigits` enough? At least with this example the result seems fine if I remove `maparabic`.

Comment: (a) Both indexes are writing to the same `.adx` file. Use different file extensions for each index: like `.and`, `.adx`, `.tdx`, `.tnd`. (b) `fontspec`'s mapping (as called by `polyglossia` only works in xelatex; lualatex has an error message in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to answers by [Javier Bezos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735/javier-bezos) and [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada), I was able to find out the problems in my code. Here are the fixes that need to be made.

In the `latexmkrc` file, we need configurations for two indexes. So this is now the `latexmkrc` file should look like.

```
add_cus_dep( 'adx', 'and', 0, 'ndx2nnd' );
add_cus_dep( 'ndx', 'nnd', 0, 'ndx2nnd' );
sub ndx2nnd {return return Run_subst( "makeindex -o %D %S" );}
push @generated_exts, 'ndx', 'nnd', 'adx', 'and';
```

In the `main.tex` file, we need to make two fixes: (1) change `\babelprovide[mapdigits,maparabic,main]{hindi}` to just `\babelprovide[mapdigits,main]{hindi}` (2) change `\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{लेखकसूची}` to `\newindex{aut}{ndx}{nnd}{लेखकसूची}`. The final `main.tex` file which will work with the above `indexmkrc` file

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[mapdigits,main]{hindi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\newindex{top}{adx}{and}{विषयसूची}
\newindex{aut}{ndx}{nnd}{लेखकसूची}
\renewcommand\hindichaptername{अध्याय}
\begin{document}
\chapter{प्रस्तावना}
\section{परिचय}
हम किंकर्तव्यविमूढ हैं।
\index[top]{विषय १}
\index[aut]{लेखक १}
\printindex[top]
\printindex[aut]
\end{document}
```

Thanks again to Javier and Cicada for their help.